# Flot chart xaxis values overlap instead of stacking

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to get my data to show as bars for each sku, with each bar representing either current stock or projected stock.

Currently the bars are showing as stacked, but that won't look right because sometimes the projected and current are identical, so they just overlap.

If I change `stack` to false it still stays stacked.

Additionally, the tooltip will not show up on any of the bars.

What is misconfigured here?

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/4jjvkvsv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Stacking**

If two identical bars are stacked, they don't overlap. Overlap only occurs if one of the bar values is negative and the other positive.

The `stack` option belongs in the `series` option object:

```
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: 'center',
            barWidth: 0.6
        },
        stack: true
    },
```

When you try `true` and `false` here you see the difference.

If you don't want any overlap at all you may want to look at or try side-by-side-bars (there are two [plugins](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/) for that).

**2) Tooltips**

You have `tooltip` options but no tooltip plugin which understands and/or uses them. But you can simply build your own tooltip without a plugin. See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jjvkvsv/2/):

```
$("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    display: "none",
    border: "1px solid #fdd",
    padding: "2px",
    "background-color": "#fee",
    opacity: 0.80
}).appendTo("body");

$("#stock-projections-bar-chart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
        $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
            .css({
            top: item.pageY + 5,
            left: item.pageX + 5
        }).fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahh, excellent! How would I get current and projected bars to sit side-by-side?

Comment: Try out the plugins I linked to. I haven't used them so I can't give you a full explanation.